# Invalid content was found starting with element 'hc:html'

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am using *iReport 5.2.0*.

I put only html-component to the report.

In *iReport* preview it is working fint, but on *JasperReports Server* the error occurred:

[image]

I also refer this link :

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541478/error-filling-report-htmlcomponent-hchtml

In this link set 2 extension property.

In *iReport* and also *Jaspersoft Studio* where this two property set?

I also add jasperreports-htmlcomponent-5.0.1.jar but still same error is occurred.

So please help me solve this error and set to this properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restart the jasper services after copying the jasperreports-htmlcomponent-5.0.1.jar

```
 \Jaspersoft\iReport-5.1.0\ireport\modules\ext\
```

To :-

```
 JasprReportServer\apache-tomcat\Web-Inf\lib\
```